# How to send a signal to a running Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am running a script that basically has a loop inside a loop. I need some way to signal this script to break out of the inner loop.

```
repeat
   doxyz
   repeat
      doSoreWork
      if signalPresent then
         exit repeat
      end if
   end repeat
end repeat
```

I've been searching but AS doesn't appear to have any such facility. One possible way I can think of is using a file. The inner loop could monitor for the existence of it and if found break the loop. It is crude and I don't like it. Is there a better way?

EDIT:

I've been looking at [Bash Scripts using signals to break the loops](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/send-signal-to-infinite-loop-in-script.html). So far it works fairly well, though it is still ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the existence of something at the head of the loop, using while

for example, this will count out loud, so long as there's a file on the desktop called 'tester.rtf

```
set fileTarget to (path to desktop folder as text) & "tester.rtf" 
tell application "System Events"
    set x to 1
    repeat while (exists file fileTarget)
        set x to x + 1
        say x
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is neater but doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: As you didn't say what your signal was, I used your example, the presence of a file.